# jQuery to select elements from multiselect dropdown through checkboxes

Tags: jquery, checkbox

There are 2 group of colors "Main Colors" and "Rest of Colors".
Main Colors => Red, Green, Blue, Yellow
Rest of Colors => Black, Magenta, Rose, White

I have put the colors in multiselect dropdown:

```
<select id="multipeColorSelect" multiple size="8">
    <option class="main" value="Red">Red</option>
    <option class="main" value="Green">Green</option>
    <option class="main" value="Blue">Blue</option>
    <option class="main" value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
    <option class="other" value="Black">Black</option>
    <option class="other" value="Magenta">Magenta</option>
    <option class="other" value="Rose">Rose</option>
    <option class="other" value="White">White</option>
</select>
```

I have 2 checkboxes for it.

```
<label>Main colors
    <input type="checkbox" data-class="main" name="colorcheckbox" value="maincolors" />
</label>
<label>Rest of colors
    <input type="checkbox" data-class="other" name="colorcheckbox" value="restofcolors" />
</label>
```

In the below code,
1) If any one color in "Main Colors" group is selected, the other "Rest of Colors" checkbox will be disabled.
2) If any one color in "Rest of Colors" group is selected, the other "Main Colors" checkbox will be disabled.

```
$('input[name="colorcheckbox"]').click(function () {
    $('#multipeColorSelect option.' + $(this).data("class")).prop('selected', $(this).prop("checked"));
});

$('#multipeColorSelect').change(function () {
    var mainChecked = 0;
    var otherChecked = 0;

    $(this).find("option").each(function() {
        if ($(this).prop("selected")) {
            $(this).hasClass("main") ? mainChecked++ : otherChecked++;
        }        
    });

    $("input[data-class='other']").prop("disabled", mainChecked == 1);
    $("input[data-class='main']").prop("disabled", otherChecked == 1);

    if ($('#multipeColorSelect option[value="Black"]:checked').length > 0 && $('#multipeColorSelect option[value="Blue"]:checked').length) {
        $("input[data-class='other'], input[data-class='main']").prop("disabled", false);
    }

});
```

Sorry for the change:
1) If "Red" and "Green" or "Green" and "Blue" or "Blue and "Yellow" are selected, the other "Rest of Colors" checkbox should be unchecked.
2) If "Black" and "Magenta" or "Magenta" and "Rose" or "Rose and "White" are selected, the other "Main Colors" checkbox should be unchecked.

Also, please let me know if jQuery code can be simplified in a better manner.
Please help.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5u63yu8t/1/):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use $.inArray and save the values of colors selected by the user in an array.
You can check JsFiddle and see if the code i made solve you problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/5u63yu8t/5/

```
$('#multipeColorSelect').change(function () {
       var optClass = [];
       var values = $(this).val();
       $("input[data-class='other'], input[data-class='main']").attr("disabled", false);

       for (var i = 0; i<values.length; i++) {

        optClass.push(($('#multipeColorSelect option[value="'+values[i]+'"]').attr('class')));        
    }

    if ($.inArray("main", optClass) !== -1) {

        $("input[data-class='other']").attr("disabled", true);
    }

    if ($.inArray("other", optClass) !== -1) {    
        $("input[data-class='main']").attr("disabled", true);
    }

    if ($.inArray("Black", values) !== -1 && $.inArray("Yellow", values) !== -1 && values.length === 2) {

        $("input[data-class='other'], input[data-class='main']").attr("disabled", false);    
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Does this solve your problem?

```
$('input[name="colorcheckbox"]').click(function () {
    $('#multipeColorSelect option.' + $(this).data("class")).prop('selected', $(this).prop("checked"));
});

$('#multipeColorSelect').change(function () {
    var mainChecked = 0;
    var otherChecked = 0;

    $(this).find("option").each(function() {
        if ($(this).prop("selected")) {
            $(this).hasClass("main") ? mainChecked++ : otherChecked++;
        }        
    });

    $("input[data-class='other']").prop("disabled", mainChecked >= 1 && otherChecked === 0);
    $("input[data-class='main']").prop("disabled", otherChecked >= 1 && mainChecked === 0);

    if ($('#multipeColorSelect option[value="Black"]:checked').length > 0 && $('#multipeColorSelect option[value="Blue"]:checked').length) {
        $("input[data-class='other'], input[data-class='main']").prop("disabled", false);
    }
});
```